# Déjà Dup over SSH - where to enter my login credentials?

Tags: ssh, backup, deja-dup

I'm trying to make a backup of my folder in my ubuntu 12.10.

I'm using BackUp in system setting using ssh, it can go through preparation file to backup.
but then failed. cannot have permission to write

I can ssh my site with terminal, but in this Backup, I dont know where to type my userid and pass just like in SSH.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what exactly went wrong and where you want your backup to? Should it be saved on some other computer in your network? Right now it is hard to tell what your question is and therefore it's hard to give a good answer.

Comment: Instead of using password, have you considered RSA or similar keys?

Answer (score 1):

Déjà Dup uses GVFS to access the server, which is the same system that is used when you log into an SSH server with Nautilus’ “Connect to server”. You could try logging into your server using Nautilus and see if it works then.

If you use key-based authentication, you should be asked for your password as soon as Déjà Dup tries to connect to your server.